# ` '$props' is declared but its value is never read.` error occurred in Vue3/TypeScript project while '$props' has not been explicitly used

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

**Vue3** component with **TypeScript** and **vue-property-decorator**:

```
<template lang="pug">

component.OverflowSafeSingleLineLabel(
  :is="rootElementTag"
)
  span.OverflowSafeSingleLineLabel-TextWithIncreasedLineHeight
    slot

</template>


<script lang="ts">

  import { Options, Vue, Prop as VueProperty } from "vue-property-decorator";


  @Options ({})
  export default class OverflowSafeSingleLineLabel extends Vue {

    @Prop({ type: String, default: "div" })
    protected readonly rootElementTag!: string;
  }

</script>
```

I have 4 TypeScript errors:

```
ERROR in C:\Users\XXX\Source\OverflowSafeSingleLineLabel.vue.ts
5:45-51
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\XXX\Source\OverflowSafeSingleLineLabel.vue.ts(5,46)
      TS6133: '$props' is declared but its value is never read.

ERROR in C:\Users\XXX\Source\OverflowSafeSingleLineLabel.vue.ts
5:57-63
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\XXX\Source\OverflowSafeSingleLineLabel.vue.ts(5,58)
      TS6133: '$setup' is declared but its value is never read.

ERROR in C:\Users\XXX\Source\OverflowSafeSingleLineLabel.vue.ts
5:69-74
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\XXX\Source\OverflowSafeSingleLineLabel.vue.ts(5,70)
      TS6133: '$data' is declared but its value is never read.

ERROR in C:\Users\XXX\Source\OverflowSafeSingleLineLabel.vue.ts
5:80-88
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\XXX\Source\OverflowSafeSingleLineLabel.vue.ts(5,81)
      TS6133: '$options' is declared but its value is never read.
```

I can't understand on what the error refers for.
The line 5 is the `template` part. Where I declared `'$props'`,  `'$setup'`, `'data'` and `'$options'`?

[Repro repository](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/Yamato-Daiwa-Frontend/tree/0.3.0/FrameworksIntegrations/Vue/Package) (Well, it's not the repro, but currently there nothing except basic scaffold like `package.json`, Webpack config and 2 source files).

[ZIP with included `node_modules`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YtDvwyGCiPAh8HvPgc-13-l46RiqaVdl/view?usp=sharing) Just run `webpack` to get the above erroneous output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with Vue3 template code generation. There is an open issue here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/issues/4668

The latest comment:

> Ah, so it is a problem with Vue's codegen in the sense that it generates unused parameters sometimes - which previously wasn't an issue as the generated render function wasn't actually typechecked, but vue-tsc now does that.
>
> so there's little for you to do, we'll have to research if/how we can improve this.

They suggest a workaround like following in `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
}
```